# Simply queries in pandas give different results

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

I am doing simply queries on a csv document about a genome. I have the following code:

```
locus_example = 'Rv0001'

for locus in tuberculosis_data1["Locus"].values:
    if locus_example.rfind(locus):
        result = tuberculosis_data1.loc[tuberculosis_data1['Locus'] == locus]['Sequences'].values
        for r in result:
            print(r)
        break
```

That gives me the following sequence:

```
ATGGACGCGGCTACGACAAGAGTTGGCCTCACCGACTTGACGTTTCGTTTGCTACGAGAGTCTTTCGCCGATGCGGTGTCGTGGGTGGCTAAAAATCTGCCAGCCAGGCCCGCGGTGCCGGTGCTCTCCGGCGTGTTGTTGACCGGCTCGGACAACGGTCTGACGATTTCCGGATTCGACTACGAGGTTTCCGCCGAGGCCCAGGTTGGCGCTGAAATTGTTTCTCCTGGAAGCGTTTTAGTTTCTGGCCGATTGTTGTCCGATATTACCCGGGCGTTGCCTAACAAGCCCGTAGACGTTCATGTCGAAGGTAACCGGGTCGCATTGACCTGCGGTAACGCCAGGTTTTCGCTACCGACGATGCCAGTCGAGGATTATCCGACGCTGCCGACGCTGCCGGAAGAGACCGGATTGTTGCCTGCGGAATTATTCGCCGAGGCAATCAGTCAGGTCGCTATCGCCGCCGGCCGGGACGACACGTTGCCTATGTTGACCGGCATCCGGGTCGAAATCCTCGGTGAGACGGTGGTTTTGGCCGCTACCGACAGGTTTCGCCTGGCTGTTCGAGAACTGAAGTGGTCGGCGTCGTCGCCAGATATCGAAGCGGCTGTGCTGGTCCCGGCCAAGACGCTGGCCGAGGCCGCCAAAGCGGGCATCGGCGGCTCTGACGTTCGTTTGTCGTTGGGTACTGGGCCGGGGGTGGGCAAGGATGGCCTGCTCGGTATCAGTGGGAACGGCAAGCGCAGCACCACGCGACTTCTTGATGCCGAGTTCCCGAAGTTTCGGCAGTTGCTACCAACCGAACACACCGCGGTGGCCACCATGGACGTGGCCGAGTTGATCGAAGCGATCAAGCTGGTTGCGTTGGTAGCTGATCGGGGCGCGCAGGTGCGCATGGAGTTCGCTGATGGCAGCGTGCGGCTTTCTGCGGGTGCCGATGATGTTGGACGAGCCGAGGAAGATCTTGTTGTTGACTATGCCGGTGAACCATTGACGATTGCGTTTAACCCAACCTATCTAACGGACGGTTTGAGTTCGTTGCGCTCGGAGCGAGTGTCTTTCGGGTTTACGACTGCGGGTAAGCCTGCCTTGCTACGTCCGGTGTCCGGGGACGATCGCCCTGTGGCGGGTCTGAATGGCAACGGTCCGTTCCCGGCGGTGTCGACGGACTATGTCTATCTGTTGATGCCGGTTCGGTTGCCGGGCTGA
```

I also have the following code that is supposed to give me the same exact sequence:

```
gen_example = 'dnaA'

for gen in tuberculosis_data1["Gen name"].values:
    if gen_example.rfind(gen):
        result = tuberculosis_data1.loc[tuberculosis_data1['Gen name'] == gen]['Sequences'].values
        for r in result:
            print(r)
        break
```

However the result is:

```
TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCACCACAGTGTGGAACGCGGTCGTCTCCGAACTTAACGGCGACCCTAAGGTTGACGACGGACCCAGCAGTGATGCTAATCTCAGCGCTCCGCTGACCCCTCAGCAAAGGGCTTGGCTCAATCTCGTCCAGCCATTGACCATCGTCGAGGGGTTTGCTCTGTTATCCGTGCCGAGCAGCTTTGTCCAAAACGAAATCGAGCGCCATCTGCGGGCCCCGATTACCGACGCTCTCAGCCGCCGACTCGGACATCAGATCCAACTCGGGGTCCGCATCGCTCCGCCGGCGACCGACGAAGCCGACGACACTACCGTGCCGCCTTCCGAAAATCCTGCTACCACATCGCCAGACACCACAACCGACAACGACGAGATTGATGACAGCGCTGCGGCACGGGGCGATAACCAGCACAGTTGGCCAAGTTACTTCACCGAGCGCCCGCACAATACCGATTCCGCTACCGCTGGCGTAACCAGCCTTAACCGTCGCTACACCTTTGATACGTTCGTTATCGGCGCCTCCAACCGGTTCGCGCACGCCGCCGCCTTGGCGATCGCAGAAGCACCCGCCCGCGCTTACAACCCCCTGTTCATCTGGGGCGAGTCCGGTCTCGGCAAGACACACCTGCTACACGCGGCAGGCAACTATGCCCAACGGTTGTTCCCGGGAATGCGGGTCAAATATGTCTCCACCGAGGAATTCACCAACGACTTCATTAACTCGCTCCGCGATGACCGCAAGGTCGCATTCAAACGCAGCTACCGCGACGTAGACGTGCTGTTGGTCGACGACATCCAATTCATTGAAGGCAAAGAGGGTATTCAAGAGGAGTTCTTCCACACCTTCAACACCTTGCACAATGCCAACAAGCAAATCGTCATCTCATCTGACCGCCCACCCAAGCAGCTCGCCACCCTCGAGGACCGGCTGAGAACCCGCTTTGAGTGGGGGCTGATCACTGACGTACAACCACCCGAGCTGGAGACCCGCATCGCCATCTTGCGCAAGAAAGCACAGATGGAACGGCTCGCGGTCCCCGACGATGTCCTCGAACTCATCGCCAGCAGTATCGAACGCAATATCCGTGAACTCGAGGGCGCGCTGATCCGGGTCACCGCGTTCGCCTCATTGAACAAAACACCAATCGACAAAGCGCTGGCCGAGATTGTGCTTCGCGATCTGATCGCCGACGCCAACACCATGCAAATCAGCGCGGCGACGATCATGGCTGCCACCGCCGAATACTTCGACACTACCGTCGAAGAGCTTCGCGGGCCCGGCAAGACCCGAGCACTGGCCCAGTCACGACAGATTGCGATGTACCTGTGTCGTGAGCTCACCGATCTTTCGTTGCCCAAAATCGGCCAAGCGTTCGGCCGTGATCACACAACCGTCATGTACGCCCAACGCAAGATCCTGTCCGAGATGGCCGAGCGCCGTGAGGTCTTTGATCACGTCAAAGAACTCACCACTCGCATCCGTCAGCGCTCCAAGCGCTAG
```

The correct sequence for this gen called dnaA for locus Rv0001 is the second one. I understand that there are no more genes called dnaA, not even partially. The sequence for the first result is actually the sequence in the following row of the csv file (Rv002/dnaN)

When I remove one 0 and search Rv001 instead, it gives the correct sequence.

I can't understand why the first search is giving me the sequence for the second row while the second search is giving the correct sequence. Any idea as to why python/pandas are behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen into one of the classic Python traps.  Since `0` is a valid index in a string, the `rfind` function returns `-1` if the string is not found.  Both of your `if` statements will treat that as a win, not a fail.  You should use `if ...rfind(...) >= 0:`.

Is pandas really helping you here?  Wouldn't this be easier as a simple list of rows?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like magic. But it's still behaving differently. When I add >= to the first part, it gives me the right sequence but if I add >= to the second code, it doesn't provide any result. How could I know when it's more useful to add it and when not? Replying to you question, it's a csv file with more than 6k rows so pandas is very useful when doing more complex searches

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `rfind` here at all, instead of just `==`.    If `gen` contains any subsequence of `"dnaA"`, it will be a match.  So, `"dna"` would match, as would just `"A"`.  Aren't you looking for an exact match?

Comment: You're absolutely right! Too many hours in front of my screen and I don't even know what I am doing anymore... thanks again, Tim! You're a life saviour.